# Query to aggregate totals between dates

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have data of the following format:

```
Date        Value
08/28        100
09/01        1
09/01        5
09/10        2
```

I would like my output to be:

```
Date        Value
08/28        100
08/29        100
08/30        100
08/31        100
09/01        106
09/02        106
.
.
.
09/10        108
```

I'm just getting started with SQL, so any help would be appreciated. What I have right now is below, but that's not really close to what I seek:

```
SELECT  Date, COUNT(DISTINCT(Service)) AS Value
      FROM [Directory]
      WHERE Date <= @myDate
      GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: I'd recommend creating a `dates` or `numbers` table.  Then you can use an `outer join` to achieve your results.  Depending on your `RDBMS`, there are different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use a sub query to get the aggregate values

```
SELECT  Date, (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Directory d WHERE d.Date <= Directory.Date)
FROM [Directory]
WHERE Date <= @myDate
ORDER BY Date
```

Which would give you something that looks like this:

```
Date        Value
08/28        100
09/01        101
09/01        106
09/10        108
```

Then you can add a Date table as sgeddes suggested.  This article explains if fairly well: http://michaelmorley.name/how-to/create-date-dimension-table-in-sql-server

Then you can modify your query like so

```
SELECT DateTable.Date, (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Directory d WHERE d.Date <= Directory.Date)
FROM [Directory] LEFT OUTER JOIN DateTable on Directory.Date = DateTable.Date
WHERE DateTable.Date <= @myDate
ORDER BY DateTable.Date
```

To get the data format you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on sgeddes suggestion:

SELECT  a.Date, COUNT(DISTINCT(d.Service)) AS Value

```
  FROM [Directory] d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Date Table] a on d.Date  = a.Date 
  WHERE Date <= @myDate
  GROUP BY Date 
  ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: That still isn't showing me the in-between dates which aren't explicitly defined in [Directory]...

Answer (score 0):

**Use following script in sqlserver :**

```
BEGIN
--If exist then drop temp tables
DROP TABLE #YOURTABLE;
DROP TABLE #TEST1;

DECLARE @MINDATE DATETIME;
DECLARE @MAXDATE DATETIME;

CREATE TABLE #YOURTABLE(
CDATE DATE,
VALUE INT
);
INSERT INTO #YOURTABLE VALUES ('08/28/2014',100),('09/01/2014',1),('09/01/2014',5),('09/10/2014',100);

--select start date and end date from your table
SELECT @MINDATE=MIN(CDATE),@MAXDATE=MAX(CDATE) FROM #YOURTABLE;

CREATE TABLE #TEST1(
CDATE DATE,
VALUE INT
);

;WITH CALENDAR
AS (
    SELECT @MINDATE CDATE   
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT CDATE + 1
    FROM CALENDAR
    WHERE CDATE + 1 <= @MAXDATE
    )

-- insert all dates with 0 value in temp table
INSERT INTO #TEST1 SELECT CDATE,0 FROM CALENDAR;

--delete dates which are already there in your table
DELETE FROM #TEST1 WHERE CDATE IN (SELECT CDATE FROM #YOURTABLE)

-- insert all dates with values from your table to temporary table which holds dates which are not in your table
INSERT INTO #TEST1 SELECT * FROM #YOURTABLE;

  SELECT T1.CDATE,(SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM #TEST1 T2 WHERE T2.CDATE<=T1.CDATE) FROM #TEST1 T1
END
```